# how to check WiFi connection is automatic or established manually in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, connection, android-wifi

I am doing a small android application, which will show established WiFi connection is automatic or Manuel. Is it possible to take WiFi access point which is set by user in default "setting" application?

Thanks, Vani

Comment: do you want to do WiFi setting by code ?

Comment: no i want to check established WiFi connection is automatic or manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this

```
 [ www.developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html]
```

or

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
 if (wifiManager != null) {
     WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
     if (info != null) {
        String ssid = info.getSSID();
        ...
   }           
 }
```