# Application Crashes during wifi network connection

Tags: android, wifimanager

I'm making an app where the user needs to be connected to a local wifi network.  When the user opens the app, I check to see if wifi is connected and then if they are connected to the right router.

I written my app such that CheckWifiConnection() is called after BroadcastReceivers on WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION, SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION, and SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.

My app crashes when the user starts up with wifi disabled.  An alert comes up asking to turn on wifi.  Once wifi is enabled, the BroadcastReceiver calls CheckWifiConnection() and crashes on info.getSSID() saying:
    `error receiving broadcast intent act=android.net.wifi.wifi_state_changed`

It crashes because I'm in the process of connecting to a wifi network after the radio has turned on.  If I simply put a Handler.postDelayed call in, then it works.

Here is the pertinent code.
A chunk of my manifest file:
    
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>`
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

```
/********************* Wifi Related Functions **********************/
private boolean CheckWifiConnection() {
    // Connect to Wifi if not enabled
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Wifi not on");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("This app needs Wifi On");
        builder.setMessage("Is that OK?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                Log.d(TAG,"Turning WIFI on");
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // For the time being connect to WIFI anyway
                // Probably change to a toast and exit program
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        checkWifiStatus = true;

        builder.show();
        return false;
    }

    Log.d(TAG,"Wifi is On");

    // See if they are connected to configured router
    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    Log.d(TAG,"Have Wifi Info");
    if ( info.getSSID().matches(router) == false) {
        // Do a scan to see if they can see us
        wifiManager.startScan();
        Log.d(TAG,"Starting Network Scan");
        return false;
    }

    return true;

} 


private BroadcastReceiver wifiConnectionChanged = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i){
        if (checkWifiStatus && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"WIFI is now on");
            checkWifiStatus = false;
            CheckWifiConnection();
        }       
    }

};
```

Is there a way to check if I am in the process of connecting to a router and/or a BroadcastReceiver for when I connect to a Wifi network?  I feel like putting a pause in my code is admitting defeat, and likely to cause problems down the line.

Also, If there is a better way of doing all of these checks, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: see this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924401/how-to-check-wifi-connection-is-automatic-or-established-manually-in-android/8924531#8924531

Comment: I added in a check for (info == null).  But that doesn't fix the problem.  It still crashes without the pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NagarjunaReddy,  your link led me on the right path to find the solution.  If the wifi antenna is in the process of connecting, then info is not null, but info.getSSID() is.  Thus it appears to be better to write:

```
WifiInfo info = WifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (info.getSSID() != null) {
    String ssid = info.getSSID();
    ...
}
```

I don't know if it would be overkill to write:

```
if (info != null && info.getSSID() != null)
```

Also, the BroadcastReceiver that I need to monitor when a connection is made is 
WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION.  It turns out that I had a copy and paste error in my onResume(), and I wasn't really registering WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION.